# Using Nodemon or something similar to listen for changes, first build, then start?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Using Nodemon or something similar to listen for changes, first build, then start?  Is it possible?

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "npm run build:dll && webpack --progress",
  "start": "node app.js",
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure nodemon is installed (*npm install -g nodemon* or *npm install --save-dev nodemon*) and then just change your package.json to this:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "babel lib -d build --copy-files",
  "start": "nodemon build/index.js" 
}
```

**EDIT:**
Add a *nodemon.json* on the root of your project, in there insert your build script in the "events.restart" section as documented here: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/sample-nodemon.md

```
"events": {
    "restart": "your build script here"
  }
```

And finally run with "npm run start". This run your app with nodemon and nodemon's configuration will execute your build very time you change your code (on restart)

Comment: that doesn't seem to execute the build first

Comment: @benishky If you want to run multiple scripts, you can append them `"start": "build && nodemon build/index.js"`

Comment: @k0pernikus thanks for the advice.  What command do I run to kick it off?  "npm start"?  "nodemon start"  Will it be listening for changes and re-run? Sorry for the newb questions...but everything I've tried doesn't work (I've inherited this project)

Comment: Sorry, re-reading your question I think it should be something on nodemon's side, since that'll be the one listening to changes and you want to rebuild when you change something. I've edited my answer ;-) please check that